# angularJS ng-options change default option's value to null

Tags: angularjs

Because of some reasons, I have to code like this:

```
 <select ng-model="value" ng-options = "item.value as item.label for item in item">
    <option value="">all</option>
 </select>
```

but when I migrate to angularjs1.5,  ngOptions change the option(value is empty string) to :

```
<option value="?" selected="selected"></option>
<option value class>all</option>
<option label="yes" value="string:true">yes</option>
<option label="no" value="string:false">no</option>
```

and the option's value change to be `null`, I dont want `null` and I set the modelValue to be `''` (`$scope.value = ''`), the `select` can't choose the `all` option, what can I do to make the select distinguish the `''`

Comment: add `ng-disabled="true"` to that option

Comment: @manish it's not about disabled attribute, I want it can choose when the value is `''`

Comment: dude you must reframe your question